# No GROUP function is working on asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, ivr, pbx

I have a Sagoma 8 port card with PRI PSTN DAHDI lines.To manage the traffic I am trying to use the [group function](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+groups) to get the statistics. Below is the code

```
same => n,Set(Group=g1)
same => n,Set(GCOUNT=${GROUP_MATCH_COUNT(${GROUP})})
same => n,NoOp(---Count--${GROUP}---${GCOUNT}---${GROUP_LIST()}----)
```

Which prints

```
---Count--g1---0-------
```

But there is traffic on that DID, similarly I tried other functions like `GROUP()`,`GROUP_LIST()` that also dint work.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

`core show functions` display then method definition means it is compatible the why I am not able to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using asterisk functions incorrect, as varables. You should use it as functions

```
exten =>s,1,Set(GROUP(class)=item);
exten =>s,n,Noop(${GROUP_COUNT(item@class)})
```

If you not want class, you still should use function(it case sensitive and have "()"):

```
  exten =>s,1,Set(GROUP()=item);
  exten =>s,n,Noop(${GROUP_COUNT(item)})
```

That is actually item@default.